# Filter a dataframe based on subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

The following is the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B' : [11, 11, 12, 12, 13,14,15],
                   'C' :[0.12232, 0.12232, 0.3455, 0.3455, 0.112, 0.567, 0.8901],
                   'D' :[False, True, True, True, True, True, True],
                   'E' :[True, True, False, True, True, True, True],
                   'F' :[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]})

   A   B        C      D      E      F
0  1  11  0.12232  False   True  False
1  1  11  0.12232   True   True   True
2  2  12  0.34550   True  False  False
3  2  12  0.34550   True   True   True
4  3  13  0.11200   True   True   True
5  4  14  0.56700   True   True   True
6  5  15  0.89010   True   True   True
```

using drop_duplicates  with subset column list of dataframe does not work for me. please let me know, how to do this in a simple and fast way

If the values of columns A, B, C are duplicated. Please check if D, E, F are True, remove that row from the dataframe.

expected output dataframe:

```
   A   B        C      D      E      F
0  1  11  0.12232  False   True  False
2  2  12  0.34550   True  False  False
4  3  13  0.11200   True   True   True
5  4  14  0.56700   True   True   True
6  5  15  0.89010   True   True   True
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(list('ABC'))` ? how is this different to your previously asked (deleted) question?

Comment: @anky_91 It don't filter the dataframe. I need a condition that checks if all the DEF values are true and if the corresponding ABC values are duplicates. then remove that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to check **`A,B and C`** + [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to check  **`D,E and F`**. [`Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) is used here to do the `AND` operation between both boolean Series 
to make the code cleaner:

```
m =(  df.duplicated(subset = ['A','B','C'],keep = False)
        .mul(df[['D','E','F']].all(axis=1)) )
df.loc[~m]
```

**Output**

```
   A   B        C      D      E      F
0  1  11  0.12232  False   True  False
2  2  12  0.34550   True  False  False
4  3  13  0.11200   True   True   True
5  4  14  0.56700   True   True   True
6  5  15  0.89010   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way:

```
t = (df['D'] == True) & (df['E'] == True) & (df['F'] == True) # check where D, E, F are True
e = df.duplicated(subset=['A','B', 'C']) # Check duplicates in A, B, C
a = (e == True) & (e == True) # Check where duplicates are true in D, E, F
a = a.index[a].tolist() # get the index
df = df.drop(index=a) # drop duplicates True in D, E, F
print(df)

#    A   B        C      D      E      F
# 0  1  11  0.12232  False   True  False
# 2  2  12  0.34550   True  False  False
# 4  3  13  0.11200   True   True   True
# 5  4  14  0.56700   True   True   True
# 6  5  15  0.89010   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using helper columns to subset logically by:

```
df = df.assign(grp_count = lamba x: x.groupby(['A','B','C']).transform('count'),
               sum_bool = lamba x: x.reindex['D','E','F'].sum(axis=1))

sub_df = (df[(df['grp_count'] > 1 & df['sum_bool'] != 3) | (df['grp_count'] == 1)]
           .drop(columns=['grp_count', 'sum_bool']))
```